# Yii2 rest api ActiveDataProvider, use some max element id instead of pagination

Tags: php, api, rest, yii2

I'm developing rest api using Yii2.

My problem seems very trivial, but I don't know how to search for any information about it.

Let's view an example:

1. I have 3 category in the database:

   - A1
   - A2
   - A4
2. ActiveDataProvider, by default return only 3 categories. Categories ordered by title and api will return first 3 categories(A1, A2, A4) for the mobile application
3. Somebody insert new category with name **A3**
4. Then application try to get next page with categories, and api will return (A4 again), so user will see the list of categories where category A4 is displaied twice.

The idea, that I have is use custom GET param, which will store max id from the list of elements, which returned in the previous request, I'm going to extend default Serializer to remove linksEnvelope, and update paginationEnvelope, etc...

But I think, that my solution is not the best one, maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: To get the best help you should post your code.

Comment: More generally, I'm interesting in theory. If there are any default mechanism for such issues in Yii2 or how it's done in facebook api, for example

Comment: @Levchukivan what do you mean that `ActiveDataProvider` by default returns only 3 categories. It depends on code you write. It will really help to understand this concept if you include code in here.

Comment: @Mike Ross I know, that by it depends on the code, it was just an example. I don't need any help with my code, but if you insist, I will provide  it. I need some kind of best practice for such issue

Comment: I guess if you want to have functionality like everyone should have the "realtime" data of the page you have to query and change them through some ajax requests. 
e.g. you could do something similar like stackoverflow which checks for new questions/edits in the background and adds "xy new questions" or "an edit has been made click to reload" to the page as an information for the user. Then they have to manually refresh the content by clicking it.

Comment: Thanks, this is something close that I'd like to know. But, I'm interesting in the situation, when mobile application has infinite scroll, for example. Also, I'm wondering if something done for it in Yii2 (but as it seems to me, there is nothing, I'm really surprised, because, as I told, this issue seems very trivial for me)

Comment: if your app has an infinite scroll you normally add new items to the bottom. And the order is given by the primary auto increment key which is always higher then the id before (also when you delete one in between). So the order is always the same! Your example was by sorting by some "name" and add an item in between existing items. If you then would have a paginated grid AND want the order by the name ascending there is no other way then refresh page/grid.  
But as i written above for an grid sorted by id only the pagination would "grow" but not the content on the individual pages.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the grid, and there is no problems to use grid with pagination on the website.
But I don't understand, why, for example, I can't use infinite scroll on the mobile application, for some list of users, where users are sorted by names, and if user has already downloaded first 10 users, next response should not contain user with id = 10, if new user was added between existing items